# Yii2 gridview filter virtual attribute textfield showing a number by default

Tags: gridview, yii2, filtering, virtual-attribute

Model:

```
public $FnGdiff;

public function getFnGdiff() {
    return $this->FnG - $this->fd;
}
```

ModelSearch:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['fnGdiff'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

now if I add `fnGdiff` to gridview, there is always **a number**(?!) by default in the textfield where we can do filtering. It is zero, -6, etc. Is it a feature, or a bug, or have I forgotten something to adjust? Many thanks in advance!

SOLUTION:

Model:

```
public function getFnGdiff() {
    return $this->FnG - $this->fd;
}
```

ModelSearch:

```
public $fnGdiff;

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['fnGdiff'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
...
```

*(So this strange number is disappeared, however it's not possible to filter a calculated virtual attribute this way, you have to select such a field from DB in order to be able to do that)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `fnGdiff` t your gridView  .. you invoke the function  getFnGdiff() .. that seems return 0 by default  ..

```
 could be You want show  $FnGdiff
```

be careful with naming convention for function and vars

```
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        .....
        'FnGdiff',   // $FnGdiff content
        'fnGdiff',  // function getFnGdiff() result
```

and you should move the  code for vars and function to searchModel

ModelSearch

```
 public $FnGdiff;

 public function getFnGdiff() {
   return $this->FnG - $this->fd;
}
```

and remove this code from model ..

Comment: I assume I have to add `fnGdiff` because `FnGdiff` is empty.

Comment: what do you mean with your  comment  ..  obvious  FnGdiff .. is empty .. explain better .. .. asnwer  updated with sume suggestion ..

Comment: If not like this, then how should I define a calculated virtual attribute, to be able to filter it, without any numbers by default in the textfield?

Comment: here you can find some sample  .. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/  ... but is another question respect to your  ..above ..

Comment: Thanks I have seen this article already, and I don't find any details that would make it clear what have I done wrong, or what should I do otherwise to make this strange behavior disappear.

Comment: the part  related  to calculated  value for fullname is what you should eval deeply

Comment: I have update the answer   adding a brief  (but important ) suggestion ..

Comment: if I remove this code from Model, then I get **UnknownPropertyException**

Comment: then   you are referring to the calculated  value  in model ... i suggest you to take another deep exam of the link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/ ..

Comment: You are right: ModelSearch: public $fnGdiff2; rules: [['fnGdiff2'], 'safe'], Model: function. Now it works as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Filter filed is render for search model and their attributes passed to GridView. When you create that model, virtual attribute $FnGdiff is set by specified value when model is initial before send query. Your attribute $FnGdiff is deafault set 0 ($this->FnG - $this->fd, in new model it is: null - null = 0), and that value is render in text filter field. So you should return specified value only for no new record. Try this:

```
public function getFnGdiff() {
    return $this->isNewRecord ? '' : $this->FnG - $this->fd;
}
```

Comment: And why can it be **-6** also? I think it is somehow keeping the last calculated value or something like this.

Comment: How about attributes $FnG and $fd? Where are initialized?

Comment: These are from DB

Comment: Try to debug their values after init model. Check why $this->FnG - $this->fd equal -6. Try to debug it eg. `throw new \Exception('Fng: ' . var_export($this->FnG, true) . 'fd: ' . var_export($this->fd, true));`